# Required tolerance for camera calibration target

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

In reading about and experimenting with camera calibration I haven't seen any mention of the required tolerance for the placement of calibration targets. For example say I have a field of view of 200mm x 30mm and I want to be able to measure the position of objects in this field to within 1mm. I will calibrate my camera using a grid pattern and the OpenCV calibrateCamera flow. Say my calibration target is a printed chessboard grid with 5mm pitch. What is the tolerance on that 5mm spacing between corners on my target? Does a tighter tolerance result in more accurate pixel to real-world transformation? Does a tighter tolerance result in better distortion removal?
Note I'm measuring objects on a 2D plane, no depth measurement, and unfortunately I don't have the ability to move the calibration targets around and take multiple views of it. So I'm talking specifically about calibrating using a single view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calibration using a single view is a poor idea, generally speaking, because of the small number of independent samples it entails, so it is possible that tolerance on the calibration grid manufacture be the least of your worries. But if you must...

The controlling factor here is the sensor's dot pitch. Given the nominal focal length of your lens, and that you want your calibration RMSE to be order of a few tenths of pixel, you can work out the angle spanned by, say, 1/10 of a pixel along the sensor's horizontal axis. Back projecting that at the nominal distance between the lens's exit pupil and the target will give you a length in 3D world that measures the uncertainty in a target's corner location at the calibration optimum. Your physical target points should be known at least as accurately, and normally better.

Example:
Setup: Dot pitch 5um, 16mm focal lens, 200mm working distance to target.

- Backprojected 1/10 pixel: `200/16*0.5um =~ 6um`.
- Backprojected 1/2 pixel : `200/16*2.5um =~ 31um`.

You can loosen that if you assume perfect Chi-square scaling of the errors with the square root of the number of the data points. If you have, say, 100 corners, you can multiply that by 10, i.e. ~ 300um for 1/2 pixel

Note that with this kind of tolerances temperature control (for camera and target) may become a factor to keep into account.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I want to make sure I understand. When you say the sensor's dot pitch, are you talking about the pixel pitch? The distance between pixels? My pixels are ~5um x 5um, and there are 2048 in the horizontal direction, and I'm using a 16mm focal length with say a 200mm working distance. So if 1/10 of a pixel is 0.5um what is that angle you refer to along the horizontal axis. Thank you again for the answer

Comment: Edited with an example calculation